# Is there a way to retrieve a variable name assigned to a TableLayout object to identify one from another?

Tags: java, android, tablelayout

**Problem:** I'm having difficulty finding a way to identify which of two TableLayout objects are being passed to a method.

**What I'm trying to do:** I'm trying to use Singleton class with list of Static methods that perform common setup functions when creating and or editing a `TableLayout` programmatic-ally.

For example, since creating an 'add' `Button` within a `TableRow` for each `TableLayout` is identical except for the button `OnClickListener` action, I would like to simply pass the TableLayout object. I then use the TableLayout variable name of that object to identify the correct OnClickListener setup.

In the code example below, the `if - else` is an example of what I would like to do. I know there isn't a method `name()`... it is my way of demonstrating in the code what I would like to do.

```
private Button setupAuthorsAddRowButton(Context context, TableLayout table){
    Button btnAddRow = new Button(context);
    TableRow.LayoutParams trLayoutParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(0, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    trLayoutParams.setMargins(3,3,3,3);
    btnAddRow.setLayoutParams(trLayoutParams);
    btnAddRow.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    btnAddRow.setText("+");
    btnAddRow.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT,Typeface.BOLD);
    btnAddRow.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    btnAddRow.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
    if(table.name().equals("tableLayoutAuthors"))  // name() is not a real method, just an example
        btnAddRow.setOnClickListener(v -> table.addView(setupAuthorsTableRow("", "", "", "", false)));
    else if(table.name().equals("tableLayoutFiles"))
        btnAddRow.setOnClickListener(v -> table.addView(setupFilesTableRow("", "",  false)));
    return btnAddRow;
}
```

UPDATE: Trying the `setTag()` and `getTag()` to identify the two different `TableLayout`s doesn't seem to be working. The `mTag` variable appears `null`. It's possible I may not be doing it correctly, but here is the setup:

**The setTag()**

```
    tableLayoutFiles = findViewById(R.id.table_files);
    tableLayoutFiles.setTag(R.id.table_files, "tableFiles");
    tableLayoutAuthors = findViewById(R.id.table_authors);
    tableLayoutAuthors.setTag(R.id.table_authors, "tableAuthors");
```

**The getTag()**

```
    if(table.getTag()=="tableAuthors")
        btnAddRow.setOnClickListener(v -> table.addView(setupAuthorsTableRow(context, table, "", "", "", "", false)));
    else if(table.getTag()=="tableFiles")
        btnAddRow.setOnClickListener(v -> table.addView(setupFilesTableRow(context, table, "", "",  false)));
    return btnAddRow;
```

**The mTag variable**

[image: mTag]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `setTag` method, which allows you to set an arbitrary object to a view. For example:

```
logoText.setTag(R.id.table_tag_key, "Table1");
```

Then use `getTag` to retrieve it.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: Hi, I posted an update trying your suggestion, which I think is the right direction, but it doesn't seem to be working. So I posted an update for review of what I may be doing wrong.

Comment: You have to use the `getTag(int)` version, the one that supports the key parameter, which will be the same tag key you used to identify the tag. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getTag(int)